# Starting to learn biology

Tags: theoretical-biology

Well, I've not any biological background but I feel interested towards it. Can you biologists suggest me how to start? Like, from where I can start learning it, from the basic level.
I'm from engineering and physics background.

Edit- I was advised to add the fields of biology that interest me.
I would like to learn microbiology, genetics and plant biology. I should mention that I've very little to no knowledge in biology. So, advise me how to get started from basics. I really have no idea how and from where to start.

Comment: Biology is a broad field. What exactly is interesting to you? Identification of plants or animals? Genetics? Ecology?...

Comment: Things like microbiology, genetics, biology of plants and such things.